# Unable to parse module: unexpected = expecting indentation at column 1 or end of input

Tags: purescript

Wrote this code

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Data.List (List)
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)

type Entry = {
  firstName :: String,
  lastName :: String,
  address :: Address
}

type Address = {
  street :: String,
  city :: String,
  state :: String
}

type AddressBook = List Entry

showEntry :: Entry -> String
showEntry entry = entry.lastName <> ", " <>
                  entry.firstName <> ", " <>
                  showAddress entry.address

showAddress :: Address -> String                  
showAddress address = address.street <> ", " <>
                      address.city <> ", " <> 
                      address.state

main :: forall e. Eff (console :: CONSOLE | e) Unit
main = do
  log "Hello Sailor!"
  address = {street: "123 Fake St.", city: "Faketown", state: "CA"}
  showAddress address
```

everything is indented with two spaces

I get error

```
Error found:
at src/Main.purs line 34, column 11 - line 34, column 11

  Unable to parse module:
  unexpected =
  expecting indentation at column 1 or end of input


See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/ErrorParsingModule.md for more information,
or to contribute content related to this error.
```

I also tried

```
main = do
  log "Hello Sailor!"
  address :: Address 
  address = {street: "123 Fake St.", city: "Faketown", state: "CA"}
  showAddress address
```

but still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have out-of-the-blue bindings within a `do` notation, or indeed anywhere except top-level.

If you want to name an intermediate value, you have to use `let`:

```
main = do
  log "Hello Sailor!"
  let address = {street: "123 Fake St.", city: "Faketown", state: "CA"}
  showAddress address
```

In your case, since `address` doesn't depend on the previous code, you can also bind it with `where`:

```
main = do
  log "Hello Sailor!"
  showAddress address
  where
      address = {street: "123 Fake St.", city: "Faketown", state: "CA"}
```

And even at top level, you can't have bindings that just stand on their own. See that `where` at the very top after `module Main`? That means everything inside this module is `where`-bound.

So the correct statement would be this: bindings can never stand on their own, they always have to be either `let`- or `where`-bound.

Also note: you can have multiple bindings inside a single `let` or a single `where`:

```
f x = do
    let y = a + 42
        z = y * b
    pure $ z - 3
    where
         a = x + 1
         b = a * 2
```